Is this the right equivalent of `cublasSgemmStridedBatched`?
I'm trying to port some cuda code which uses cuBlas to SYCL, using oneMKL's blas. OneMKL appears to be very slow though.
This is the specific snippet
    cublasCheck(cublasSgemmStridedBatched(cublas_handle,
                                          CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_N,
                                          T, T, HS,
                                          &alpha,
                                          k, HS, T * HS,
                                          q, HS, T * HS,
                                          &beta,
                                          preatt, T, T * T,
                                          B * NH));

which schedules in parallel B*NH matmuls of shape q@k^t = (T, HS) @ (HS, T) = (T, T).
This is my SYCL version using oneMKL:

    auto trans = oneapi::mkl::transpose::trans;
    auto no_trans = oneapi::mkl::transpose::nontrans;
    oneapi::mkl::blas::column_major::gemm_batch(queue,
                                             trans, no_trans,
                                             T, T, HS,
                                             alpha,
                                             k, HS, T * HS,
                                             q, HS, T * HS,
                                             beta,
                                             preatt, T, T * T,
                                             B * NH);

My question is: are these two snippets doing the same thing? It seems like that the results are correct, but cublas is much faster than oneMKL. This was not the case for other kernels/functions I ported within the same project. Thanks in advance!

Hi Mart! oneMKL interface library calls cublasSgemmStridedBatched internally (https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneMKL/blob/91a912093ebafb92ba78f7a7868835aa0c0ef6eb/src/blas/backends/cublas/cublas_batch.cpp#L601), assuming you're using the cuBLAS backend instead of the portBLAS backend. The problem could be more to do with the way oneMKL uses cuBLAS (requiring cuBLAS handle creation, deletion, and some synchronization), but its difficult to know without actually tracing the application.

Hi, thanks for your comment! I'm not sure I understand how I should properly handle creation and deletion of the cublas handle with oneMKL. I was simply passing the queue to oneapi::mkl::blas::column_major::gemm_batch after moving the required data from the host to the device with a queue.memcpy. I've just found this example on github: https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneAPI-samples/blob/master/Libraries/oneMKL/guided_cuBLAS_examples_SYCL_Migration/02_sycl_dpct_migrated/Level-3/gemmStridedBatched.cpp -- not sure I understand the stream part, but it seems related to what you mention.

The example you linked is... confusing! It seems to be using a CPU queue, so its likely that you're actually calling the MKLCPU backend and not using the GPU at all. Perhaps take a look at this sample from the oneMKL repo instead: https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneMKL/blob/develop/examples/blas/compile_time_dispatching/level3/gemm_usm_mklcpu_cublas.cpp.

Thanks! I wanted to try that out but I got the following error on devcloud: error: no member named 'backend' in namespace 'oneapi::mkl'; did you mean 'sycl::backend'?. Do you happen to know what I could be doing wrong here?

Quick clarification - are you still targetting Nvidia GPUs?
If so, an easy mistake is to use Intel(R) oneMKL (ie. the closed-source one for Intel CPUs and Intel GPUs), and not the oneMKL interface library. Are you sure you're using the right library?
If you're using the oneMKL interface library, you should be able to use the sycl::queue associated with your Nvidia GPU, it should automatically dispatch to the cuBLAS backend anyway.
